# CiviEvent - Search by custom field

Tags: civievent, wordpress, custom-fields

**The situation**

I added a custom field to CiviEvents called **regio** (means **region** in English) and I want to be able to fetch CiviEvents by this field.

I'm on CiviCRM 4.6.6 and Wordpress 4.2.2

**The problem**

When I build the query using the API Explorer provided by CiviCRM, it always returns all CiviEvents, instead of only those to the selected region. This is the code the API Explorer generates:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Event', 'get', array(
  'debug' => 1,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'custom_10' => 1,
));
```

This gives the following results:

```
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "undefined_fields": [
        "custom_10",
        "page",
        "noheader"
    ],
    "version": 3,
    "count": 25,
    "values": [{...}, {...}]
}
```

As you can see, it says that **custom_10** apparently is an undefined field, although it is generated by the API Explorer. And by the way, there actually are CiviEvents of which the region is set to **Rotterdam**.

I have spend days trying to debug this, going through the full backtrace of this function, but couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any idea why this presumably standard Civi-feature isn't working?

This screenshot gives the full settings I made in the API Explorer.

[image]

Comment: I think this is not implemented, but work has begun. See my answer to [related question on custom fields on activities](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4865/35)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As artfulrobot suggested, this is not implemented, [but will be in V4.7](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16036)